# My Storyboard Wont Open

Tags: xcode, git, storyboard

So I went to sync my changes with Github and I ran into a few problems with main.storybaord. So I re opened Xcode, opened my project, and I saw a C next to my storyboard.
Now when I try to open it, nothing shows up except for an error message saying:

> Interface Builder was unable to determine the type of
>   "Main.storyboard".

Please Help! Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12725116/the-document-mainstoryboard-storyboard-could-not-be-opened

Comment: Right but I can't get into my storyboard at all..

Comment: Right click on your storyboard, show in folder and rename it. then Remove it from your project and add again. Do not Copy.

Comment: If you need more help add me amir.ios

Comment: Okay just did that and I get the same thing. The only difference is that now I have an A next to the Storyboard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `C` means `Merge Conflict`.

You basically have two options:

1. revert to the last working revision
2. resolve the merge conflict by picking the correct change

The first one will revert all the changes that where made since the last commit. Right click the file, choose "Source Control" / "Discard Changes in ..."

The second one is best done from the terminal. Open the terminal, go to your project root and run

```
git mergetool
```

FileMerge will open, pick the correct changes in there.

Then do a

```
git commit
```

to commit the merge.